# A chart element with the name '0' already exists in the 'SeriesCollection'

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart

i have `Chart control` that received real time data.

```
// MBit/Sec
Series seriesBps = new Series("bps");
seriesBps.Color = Color.Gray;
seriesBps.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
seriesBps.BorderWidth = 2;
seriesBps.Name = "MBit/Sec";
chart1.Series.Add(seriesBps);

//// Packets/Sec
Series seriesPps = new Series("pps");
seriesPps.Color = Color.SteelBlue;
seriesPps.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
seriesPps.BorderWidth = 2;
seriesPps.Name = "Packets/Sec";
chart1.Series.Add(seriesPps);
```

This is my timer tick event that need to add this data:

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (seriesBps.Points.Count() > 300)
          seriesBps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
      seriesBps.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);

      DataPoint _point1 = default(DataPoint);
      foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[1].Points)
      {
          item.Label = "";
          item.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
      }

      chart1.Series[1].LegendText = chart1.Series[1].Name = (wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001).ToString("#,##0");
      DataPoint Point1 = chart1.Series[1].Points[chart1.Series[1].Points.Count - 1];
      Point1.Label = chart1.Series[1].Name;

            chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;
            chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false;
            chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.BottomRight;

                // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

      if (seriesPps.Points.Count() > 300)
          seriesPps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
      seriesPps.Points.Add(wf.PacketsPerSecond);

      DataPoint _point = default(DataPoint);
      foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[2].Points)
      {
           item.Label = "";
           item.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
       }

      chart1.Series[2].LegendText = chart1.Series[2].Name = wf.PacketsPerSecond.ToString("#,##0");
      DataPoint Point = chart1.Series[2].Points[chart1.Series[2].Points.Count - 1];
       Point.Label = chart1.Series[2].Name;

      chart1.Series[2].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;
      chart1.Series[2].SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false;
      chart1.Series[2].SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.BottomRight;

      chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

This `Chart` work fine with the first `Series` but after add the second one received this error, i try to change the series name to something unique but i wont help

Comment: From the code, it seems you have three series (Series[2]). Check the series collection in debug mode.

Comment: Series.Count = 3, what does it mean ?

Comment: It means that you have three series. Check what is the name of each series then you will know which series is causing problem.

Comment: Where does it fail exactly? When you do `chart1.Series.Add(seriesPps);`?

Answer (score 1):

indexing starts at zero not 1, like any other `for i` loop . Move back each series by one.

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (seriesBps.Points.Count() > 300)
          seriesBps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
      seriesBps.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);

      DataPoint _point1 = default(DataPoint);
      foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[0].Points)
      {
          item.Label = "";
          item.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
      }

      chart1.Series[0].LegendText =  (wf.BitsPerSecond *     0.000001).ToString("#,##0");
      DataPoint Point1 = chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1];
      Point1.Label = chart1.Series[0].Name;

            chart1.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;
            chart1.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false;
            chart1.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.BottomRight;

            // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

      if (seriesPps.Points.Count() > 300)
          seriesPps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
      seriesPps.Points.Add(wf.PacketsPerSecond);

      DataPoint _point = default(DataPoint);
      foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[2].Points)
      {
           item.Label = "";
           item.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
       }

      chart1.Series[1].LegendText = wf.PacketsPerSecond.ToString("#,##0");
      DataPoint Point = chart1.Series[1].Points[chart1.Series[1].Points.Count - 1];
      Point.Label = chart1.Series[1].Name;

      chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;
      chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false;
      chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.BottomRight;

      chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the answer was to first clear the series like this:

```
_chart.Series.Clear()
```

This is important if you build your Charts dynamically